# When was Shmi sold to the Lars family?

Tags: star-wars

In *Star Wars: Episode 2 Attack of the Clones* Anakin learns that his mother, Shmi, was sold to Cliegg Lars, and was consequently freed by and married to him. Clearly this happened sometime between episodes 1 and 2 but how long, exactly, after Anakin left Tatooine did this transaction take place?

A few comments on the question [Why Didn't Qui-Gon Free Shmi Skywalker?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/10704/1234) have been suggesting that Amidala should have been able to go back and buy/free Shmi after the events in *Episode 1*. Would that have been an option at that time (did Watto still own her?), or had she already been sold to Cliegg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Wikia:

> Life as a slave (66 BBY–32 BBY)

32 BBY was when Anakin went away with the Jedi.

Comment: As a note: The wording on the Wikia is extremely vague, so I'm not at all certain that 32BBY is the correct answer. The only source I can think of - "Tattooine Ghost" book - I don't have at the moment :(